# Checking if an object's property has an empty string in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

I have an object that either contains an image URL or not.

```
{
    id: 1,
    term: "Research",
    imageURL: "",
    definition:
      "is a way of thinking and understanding various aspects of a procedure to society.",
  }
```

I created a function that is supposed to read whether the imageURL is not empty then show the image and if yes, show different content, but it throws an error that says,

> "This condition will always return 'false' since JavaScript compares
> objects by reference, not value. ts(2839)"

```
const imageURL = item.imageURL

{ imageURL === "" ? (shows with no image) : (shows with image)}
```

Is there a way to read the object's property that contains a string whether its empty or not? Thank you!

Comment: Please update the question with more details, including the type of `item` and where that type comes from. But I suspect the error relates to a different part of the code, since you clearly have `""` in the comparison, which is not an object. (If `item.imageURL` were an object type, you'd get the error *"This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'some_object_type_here' and 'string' have no overlap."*, not the error you quote.)

Comment: To be clear: If `imageURL` were a string, that usage of the conditional operator would be just fine (assuming the two bits in parentheses are just fill-ins and not the real code of the tru e and false operands.)

Comment: shows ts error that comparing objects using === will compare their references, not their values,... you can modify your conditional rendering logic first check imageURL is empty or not `{img!==""?(render img):(render alt)}`

Comment: @ullaskunder - That would show the same error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gSwyAtgIwBc8SARgFbgYDcAUKJLAsulrgQEykXVh169APTD4AFQAW2NDlkAzbChAAaeOXBQArmgQZJegJ4AHBEnnwABpyKX6bNEgggAdBCQBzABQ3C8ALyB8ADeAL4AlAwiYlIycvCKymoaYNq68PpGpmQW1ni29qiOzm6ePvl+AIRBYZH0QA The problem here is that the code the OP has quoted is either not the problem code or is incomplete. We just have to wait for them to update the question with a [mre].

Comment: You could just leave out the comparison -> `{imageURL ? <img/> : <span>no image</span>}`   This will also cope with imageURL been undefined, null or false.

Comment: The object comes from a different function from a different file. `<DummyFunc item={item}/>` which is then extracted by `item.imageURL`. I logged the data whether it is passed right and it is readable. The problem is when comparing since I'm comparing the references, not the values. If only there was a way to convert that referenced value to an actual one. I tried `const length = Number(imageURL.length)`, but it throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the length property lately, and it is working fine.

```
const object = { 
    id: 1, 
    term: "Research", 
    imageURL: "", 
    definition: "is a way of thinking and understanding various aspects of a procedure to society.", 
}

object.imageURL.lenght ? render-image : render-default-content
```

It will cast length as a number to a boolean. If the length is 0 it means the string is empty, if the length is >1 it will be true.

Comment: It does not work since its length is still a reference because the error remains the same. Although the length is readable, it is still a reference.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by it being a reference. If the string is empty it will be cast to boolean and it will be false, if it's not empty it will return true. I have this one in several places on my projects, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to return empty strings. Better make a field "nullable". Better approach is to deal with existing and not existing values, because you do not need bad data.

```
const object = { 
    id: 1, 
    term: "Research", 
    imageURL: undefined, 
    definition: "is a way of thinking and understanding various aspects of a procedure to society."
}
```

or

```
const object = { 
    id: 1, 
    term: "Research", 
    definition: "is a way of thinking and understanding various aspects of a procedure to society."
}
```

and then check it:

```
object.imageURL ? render-image : render-default-content
```